# Регулярное выражение, которое проверяет чётность количества появлений символа в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Допустим, есть строка `|дядя |Вася |23` . Нужно, чтобы регулярное выражение нашло совпадение только в том случае, если символов `|` будет чётное количество. Можно ли такое сделать чисто регулярным выражением, без привлечения средств языков программирования?

Answer (score 5):

Можно, вот:

```
^(([^|]*\|){2})*[^|]*$
```